# removing background of specific anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a code to create a bootstrap panel and add some elements and remove them when clicked on `Remove` icon. When I click on `Remove` icon, background of all elements will be removed. I don't want this to happen. I want background of particular element whose `Remove` icon is clicked to be removed. My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".remove_gly").click(function () {
        //alert('Clicked');
        //var catName = $(span).closest('a').text();
    //  var index = subscriptionArrays.indexOf(catName);
    //  if (index > -1) {
//subscriptionArrays.splice(index, 1);
    //  }

        //span.parentNode.innerHTML = span.innerHTML;
        $("a").closest(".droggIng").removeClass("droggIng"); 
    });
});
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/kqcs0pq9/8/
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `a` and add `this`

```
$(this).closest(".droggIng").removeClass("droggIng");
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$(this).closest(".droggIng").removeClass("droggIng");
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/o1k84tys/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, it will do the job-

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $(".remove_gly").click(function () {

        $(this).parent(".droggIng").removeClass("droggIng"); 
    });
});
```